# How to convert self-referencing complex Cursor to more efficient SQL code? CTE, CROSS-APPLY or something else?

Tags: sql-server, cursor, common-table-expression, cross-apply

I have the following simplified table structure. In reality Slot would be identity, and the table is newly generated few lines before, so no gaps for that column.

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
55      55          18          6
56      55          19          7
57      57          13          6
58      57          14          7
59      57          15          7
60      57          15          7
61      57          17          7
62      57          17          7
63      63          16          7
64      63          16          7
65      65          15          6
66      65          15          6
```

I need to go trhough each record in MyTable and check if all records with a smaller Slot (within the same SlotGroup) have the same ScheduleGroup but different EventNum: if so I should update the Slots above the current one within the same SlotGroup.
Resulting table should contain:

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
...
59      59          15          7
60      59          15          7
61      61          17          7
62      61          17          7
...
63      63          16          7
64      63          16          7
...
```

Since in both the SlotGroups there was a previous line having same ScheduleGroup but different EventNum.

I was thinking about CTE or CROSS APPLY, but right now I have no clue on how to start; could you please help me in finding the right solution?

At the moment the code I use is this, but there could be hundreds of lines in MyTable and I feel this is not the most efficient way to solve it.

Data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    Slot                        int --identity
  , SlotGroup                   int              NULL
  , EventNum                    int              NULL
  , ScheduleGroup               int
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(55,55,18,6)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(56,55,19,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(57,57,13,6)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(58,57,14,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(59,57,15,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(60,57,15,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(61,61,14,6)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(62,61,15,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(63,61,16,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(64,61,16,7)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(65,65,15,6)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(66,65,15,6)
```

Code:

```
-- Go trhough each record in @MyTable and check if all records with a smaller Slot
--(within the same SlotGroup) have have the same ScheduleGroup but different EventNum.
--   If so do an update of the Slots above the current one (within the same SlotGroup)
DECLARE @nStartSlot         int--Will be set later within the loop
DECLARE @nCurScheduleGroup  int
DECLARE @nCurEventNum       int
DECLARE @nCurSlotGroup      int
DECLARE @nCurSlot           int
DECLARE mtCur CURSOR FOR
 SELECT ScheduleGroup, EventNum, SlotGroup, Slot FROM @MyTable

 OPEN mtCur
 FETCH NEXT FROM mtCur INTO @nCurScheduleGroup, @nCurEventNum, @nCurSlotGroup, @nCurSlot

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
--Only the records with smaller Slot then the current one but within the same SlotGroup
--are interesting. therefore get the lowest Slot from the SAME SlotGroup. 
--(important if the current records is in a new SlotGroup based on the time splitting)
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM   @MyTable mt
                  WHERE  mt.Slot = ISNULL(@nStartSlot, 0)
                  AND    mt.SlotGroup = @nCurSlotGroup
                 )
   BEGIN
     SELECT @nStartSlot = MIN(Slot) 
     FROM   @MyTable mt 
     WHERE  mt.SlotGroup = @nCurSlotGroup
   END

--Update all records above the current records but within the same SlotGroup,
--if we find a new EventNum (but ScheduleGroup) in the current SlotGroup.
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM   @MyTable mt
              WHERE  mt.Slot >= @nStartSlot
               AND   mt.Slot <= @nCurSlot
               AND   mt.ScheduleGroup = @nCurScheduleGroup
               AND   mt.EventNum != @nCurEventNum
             )
   BEGIN
     UPDATE mt
     SET    SlotGroup = @nCurSlot
     FROM   @MyTable mt
     WHERE  mt.Slot >= @nCurSlot
       AND  mt.SlotGroup = @nCurSlotGroup

     SELECT @nStartSlot = @nCurSlot
   END

   FETCH NEXT FROM mtCur INTO @nCurScheduleGroup, @nCurEventNum, @nCurSlotGroup, @nCurSlot
 END
 CLOSE mtCur
 DEALLOCATE mtCur
```

--EDIT--
Additional data sets that should be converted

*SOURCE 1*

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
16      13          3           778
17      17          10          778
18      17          10          778
19      17          9           778
20      17          9           778
```

*RESULT 1*

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
...
19      19          9           778
20      19          9           778
```

*SOURCE 2*

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
39      39          10          778
40      39          10          778
41      39          9           778
42      39          10          778
```

*RESULT 2*

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup
39      39          10          778
40      39          10          778
41      41          9           778
42      42          10          778
```

--EDIT 2--
Additional data sets that should be converted

```
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 8        8           1         978               8
 9        8           2         978               9
 10       8           2         977               9
 11       8           2         977               9
 12       8           1         977              12
 13       8           2         978              12
 14       8           1         978              14
 15       8           2         978              15
 16       8           1         978              16
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 17      17           1         331              17
 18      17           1         331              17
 19      17           1         331              17
 20      17           1         331              17
 21      17           1         331              17
 22      17           1         331              17
 23      17           1         331              17
 24      17           1         330              17
 25      17           1         330              17
 26      17           1         330              17
 27      17           1         330              17
 28      17           1         330              17
 29      17           1         330              17
 30      17           1         330              17
 31      17           2         330              31
 32      17           2         330              31
 33      17           2         330              31
 34      17           2         330              31
 35      17           2         330              31
 36      17           2         330              31
 37      17           2         330              31
 38      17           2         331              31
 39      17           2         331              31
 40      17           2         331              31
 41      17           2         331              31
 42      17           2         331              31
 43      17           2         331              31
 44      17           2         331              31
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 32      32           2         492              32
 33      32           6         492              33
 34      32           5         492              34
 35      32           6         492              35
 36      32           6         492              35
 37      32           6         492              35
 38      32           6         493              35
 39      32           6         492              35
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
219     219          18         065             219
220     219          16         065             220
221     219           1         246             220
222     219          16         065             220
223     219          18         065             223
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 39      39          10         113              39
 40      39           9         113              40
 41      39          10         112              40
 42      39           9         112              42
 43      39           1         241              42
 44      39           2         241              44
 45      39           2         241              44
 46      39           1         241              46
 47      39           1         241              46
 48      39           2         241              48
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 46      46          14         184              46
 47      46          14         183              46
 48      46          14         183              46
 49      46           1         184              49
 50      46          15         183              49
 51      46          15         183              49
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
148     148           6         725             148
149     148           5         725             149
150     148           5         725             149
151     148           6         725             151
152     148           6         723             151
153     148           6         724             151
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
150     150           2         221             150
151     150           1         221             151
152     150           2         221             152
153     150           2         221             152
154     150           1         222             152
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
122     122           3         462             122
123     122           2         462             123
124     122           2         463             123
125     122           2         463             123
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 36      36          10         617              36
 37      36           9         617              37
 38      36          10         618              37
 39      36           9         618              39
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 97      97          22         091              97
 98      97          22         091              97
 99      97          21         091              99
100      97          22         091             100
101      97          14         092             100
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
108     108          22         463             108
109     108          23         460             108
110     108          23         460             108
111     108          22         461             108
112     108          22         461             108
113     113          21         462             113
114     113          21         462             113
115     113          22         463             113
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
156     156          11         462             156
157     156          10         462             157
158     156          10         463             157
159     156          10         463             157
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 20      20           8         283              20
 21      21           7         283              21
 22      22           9         283              22
 23      23           8         283              23
 24      24          11         283              24
 25      25          10         283              25
 26      26          12         283              26
 27      26          11         283              27
 28      26           4         282              27
 29      26           4         282              27
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
105     105           2         418             105
106     106           1         418             106
107     106           1         418             106
108     108           2         418             108
109     106           1         418             109
110     106           1         418             109
111     108           2         418             111
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 57      57          13         776              57
 58      57          14         777              57
 59      57          15         777              59
 60      57          15         777              59
 61      61          14         776              61
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 9        9           3         771               9
 10       9           3         771               9
 11       9           3         771               9
 12       9           3         771               9
 13       9           1         772               9
 14       9           1         772               9
Slot    SlotGroup   EventNum    ScheduleGroup   ExpectedSlotGroup
 81      81          21         267              81
 82      81          22         267              82
 83      81          21         267              83
 84      81          21         267              83
 85      85          22         267              85
 86      85          22         267              85
 87      85          21         267              87
```

Comment: How about posting the ddl and sample data here? Otherwise nobody can really do much to help.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately this is all I got, since I'm trying to make some old inherited code to perform a little better

Comment: Is there any reason the slot groups are always odd? or that when you update you are incrementing by 2?

Comment: @SqlZim It is just a subset of full data, I had also occurrences of even ones, so do not rely on this  :)

Comment: @SqlZim SOURCE 1 I could solve using your code and adding "or  NewSlotGroup != slotgroup" to last WHERE condition

Answer (score 0):

Using `lead()` and `lag()`

```
;with cte as (
select *
  , NewSlotGroup = min(slot) over (partition by testset, grp)
from (
  select *, grp = sum(sgrp) over (partition by testset order by slot)
  from (
    select *, sgrp = case 
      when lag(eventnum) over (partition by testset order by slot) = eventnum
        then 0
      when lag(eventnum) over (partition by testset, slotgroup order by slot) <> eventnum
       and lag(schedulegroup) over (partition by testset, slotgroup order by slot) <> schedulegroup
        then 0
      else 1
      end
    from t
    ) s
  ) g
)
update cte
  set SlotGroup  = NewSlotGroup
where SlotGroup != NewSlotGroup;
```

---

The above code conflicts with one of your new test sets, (running your cursor over this test set matches my results and not the `expectedslotgroup`. Please explain why the expected slot group changes when it does not change in similar circumstances in other test sets:

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZOH27910

```
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| TestSet | slot | slotgroup | eventnum | schedulegroup | expectedslotgroup | conflict |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|       6 |   46 |        46 |       14 |           184 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   47 |        46 |       14 |           183 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   48 |        46 |       14 |           183 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   49 |        46 |        1 |           184 |                49 | X        |
|       6 |   50 |        46 |       15 |           183 |                49 | X        |
|       6 |   51 |        46 |       15 |           183 |                49 | X        |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Full results here:

```
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| TestSet | slot | slotgroup | eventnum | schedulegroup | expectedslotgroup | conflict |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|       1 |    8 |         8 |        1 |           978 |                 8 |          |
|       1 |    9 |         9 |        2 |           978 |                 9 |          |
|       1 |   10 |         9 |        2 |           977 |                 9 |          |
|       1 |   11 |         9 |        2 |           977 |                 9 |          |
|       1 |   12 |        12 |        1 |           977 |                12 |          |
|       1 |   13 |        12 |        2 |           978 |                12 |          |
|       1 |   14 |        14 |        1 |           978 |                14 |          |
|       1 |   15 |        15 |        2 |           978 |                15 |          |
|       1 |   16 |        16 |        1 |           978 |                16 |          |
|       2 |   17 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   18 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   19 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   20 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   21 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   22 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   23 |        17 |        1 |           331 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   24 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   25 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   26 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   27 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   28 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   29 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   30 |        17 |        1 |           330 |                17 |          |
|       2 |   31 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   32 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   33 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   34 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   35 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   36 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   37 |        31 |        2 |           330 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   38 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   39 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   40 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   41 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   42 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   43 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       2 |   44 |        31 |        2 |           331 |                31 |          |
|       3 |   32 |        32 |        2 |           492 |                32 |          |
|       3 |   33 |        33 |        6 |           492 |                33 |          |
|       3 |   34 |        34 |        5 |           492 |                34 |          |
|       3 |   35 |        35 |        6 |           492 |                35 |          |
|       3 |   36 |        35 |        6 |           492 |                35 |          |
|       3 |   37 |        35 |        6 |           492 |                35 |          |
|       3 |   38 |        35 |        6 |           493 |                35 |          |
|       3 |   39 |        35 |        6 |           492 |                35 |          |
|       4 |  219 |       219 |       18 |            65 |               219 |          |
|       4 |  220 |       220 |       16 |            65 |               220 |          |
|       4 |  221 |       220 |        1 |           246 |               220 |          |
|       4 |  222 |       220 |       16 |            65 |               220 |          |
|       4 |  223 |       223 |       18 |            65 |               223 |          |
|       5 |   39 |        39 |       10 |           113 |                39 |          |
|       5 |   40 |        40 |        9 |           113 |                40 |          |
|       5 |   41 |        40 |       10 |           112 |                40 |          |
|       5 |   42 |        42 |        9 |           112 |                42 |          |
|       5 |   43 |        42 |        1 |           241 |                42 |          |
|       5 |   44 |        44 |        2 |           241 |                44 |          |
|       5 |   45 |        44 |        2 |           241 |                44 |          |
|       5 |   46 |        46 |        1 |           241 |                46 |          |
|       5 |   47 |        46 |        1 |           241 |                46 |          |
|       5 |   48 |        48 |        2 |           241 |                48 |          |
|       6 |   46 |        46 |       14 |           184 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   47 |        46 |       14 |           183 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   48 |        46 |       14 |           183 |                46 |          |
|       6 |   49 |        46 |        1 |           184 |                49 | X        |
|       6 |   50 |        46 |       15 |           183 |                49 | X        |
|       6 |   51 |        46 |       15 |           183 |                49 | X        |
|       7 |  148 |       148 |        6 |           725 |               148 |          |
|       7 |  149 |       149 |        5 |           725 |               149 |          |
|       7 |  150 |       149 |        5 |           725 |               149 |          |
|       7 |  151 |       151 |        6 |           725 |               151 |          |
|       7 |  152 |       151 |        6 |           723 |               151 |          |
|       7 |  153 |       151 |        6 |           724 |               151 |          |
|       8 |  150 |       150 |        2 |           221 |               150 |          |
|       8 |  151 |       151 |        1 |           221 |               151 |          |
|       8 |  152 |       152 |        2 |           221 |               152 |          |
|       8 |  153 |       152 |        2 |           221 |               152 |          |
|       8 |  154 |       152 |        1 |           222 |               152 |          |
|       9 |  122 |       122 |        3 |           462 |               122 |          |
|       9 |  123 |       123 |        2 |           462 |               123 |          |
|       9 |  124 |       123 |        2 |           463 |               123 |          |
|       9 |  125 |       123 |        2 |           463 |               123 |          |
|      10 |   36 |        36 |       10 |           617 |                36 |          |
|      10 |   37 |        37 |        9 |           617 |                37 |          |
|      10 |   38 |        37 |       10 |           618 |                37 |          |
|      10 |   39 |        39 |        9 |           618 |                39 |          |
|      11 |   97 |        97 |       22 |            91 |                97 |          |
|      11 |   98 |        97 |       22 |            91 |                97 |          |
|      11 |   99 |        99 |       21 |            91 |                99 |          |
|      11 |  100 |       100 |       22 |            91 |               100 |          |
|      11 |  101 |       100 |       14 |            92 |               100 |          |
|      12 |  108 |       108 |       22 |           463 |               108 |          |
|      12 |  109 |       108 |       23 |           460 |               108 |          |
|      12 |  110 |       108 |       23 |           460 |               108 |          |
|      12 |  111 |       108 |       22 |           461 |               108 |          |
|      12 |  112 |       108 |       22 |           461 |               108 |          |
|      12 |  113 |       113 |       21 |           462 |               113 |          |
|      12 |  114 |       113 |       21 |           462 |               113 |          |
|      12 |  115 |       113 |       22 |           463 |               113 |          |
|      13 |  156 |       156 |       11 |           462 |               156 |          |
|      13 |  157 |       157 |       10 |           462 |               157 |          |
|      13 |  158 |       157 |       10 |           463 |               157 |          |
|      13 |  159 |       157 |       10 |           463 |               157 |          |
|      14 |   20 |        20 |        8 |           283 |                20 |          |
|      14 |   21 |        21 |        7 |           283 |                21 |          |
|      14 |   22 |        22 |        9 |           283 |                22 |          |
|      14 |   23 |        23 |        8 |           283 |                23 |          |
|      14 |   24 |        24 |       11 |           283 |                24 |          |
|      14 |   25 |        25 |       10 |           283 |                25 |          |
|      14 |   26 |        26 |       12 |           283 |                26 |          |
|      14 |   27 |        27 |       11 |           283 |                27 |          |
|      14 |   28 |        27 |        4 |           282 |                27 |          |
|      14 |   29 |        27 |        4 |           282 |                27 |          |
|      15 |  105 |       105 |        2 |           418 |               105 |          |
|      15 |  106 |       106 |        1 |           418 |               106 |          |
|      15 |  107 |       106 |        1 |           418 |               106 |          |
|      15 |  108 |       108 |        2 |           418 |               108 |          |
|      15 |  109 |       109 |        1 |           418 |               109 |          |
|      15 |  110 |       109 |        1 |           418 |               109 |          |
|      15 |  111 |       111 |        2 |           418 |               111 |          |
|      16 |   57 |        57 |       13 |           776 |                57 |          |
|      16 |   58 |        57 |       14 |           777 |                57 |          |
|      16 |   59 |        59 |       15 |           777 |                59 |          |
|      16 |   60 |        59 |       15 |           777 |                59 |          |
|      16 |   61 |        61 |       14 |           776 |                61 |          |
|      17 |    9 |         9 |        3 |           771 |                 9 |          |
|      17 |   10 |         9 |        3 |           771 |                 9 |          |
|      17 |   11 |         9 |        3 |           771 |                 9 |          |
|      17 |   12 |         9 |        3 |           771 |                 9 |          |
|      17 |   13 |         9 |        1 |           772 |                 9 |          |
|      17 |   14 |         9 |        1 |           772 |                 9 |          |
|      18 |   81 |        81 |       21 |           267 |                81 |          |
|      18 |   82 |        82 |       22 |           267 |                82 |          |
|      18 |   83 |        83 |       21 |           267 |                83 |          |
|      18 |   84 |        83 |       21 |           267 |                83 |          |
|      18 |   85 |        85 |       22 |           267 |                85 |          |
|      18 |   86 |        85 |       22 |           267 |                85 |          |
|      18 |   87 |        87 |       21 |           267 |                87 |          |
+---------+------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting but there is a small evident error: Slot 59 & 60 should have SlotGroup 59 and not 58, the same for Slot 63 & 64. Moreover it is failing in more complicated cases (multiple jumps in same SlotGroup). It seems the right direction I was looking for, let's see if we can make it work perfectly :)

Comment: @Simone Updated my answer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm still working on it, unfortunately however your solution it is not completely correct; there are at least two combinations that are still problematic; please check my edited question

Comment: Sorry, but I fear it is not correct: slot 42 is still having slotgroup 39, while my requirement would be to have it as 42. Am I missing something?

Comment: i followed your tips, but there were still corner cases :(, added them

Comment: @Simone Can you explain why your expected results do not match the results produced by using the cursor code?

Comment: @Simone Specifically for slot groups 46 and 150 from your added test cases.

Comment: Hoping to be able to clarify :) See following comments.

Comment: Slot 46
At Slot 49 ScheduleGroup 184 has been previously found linked to different EventNum: 14 @ Slot 46; this new couple (184,1) must have a different SlotGroup and so also all the following Slots having same SlotGroup

Comment: Slot 150
At Slot 151 ScheduleGroup 221 has been previously found linked to different EventNum: 2 @ Slot 150; this new couple (221,1) must have a different SlotGroup and so also all the following Slots having the same SlotGroup.
Again at Slot 152 ScheduleGroup 221 has been previously found linked to different EventNum: 1 @ Slot 151; this new couple (221,2) must have a different SlotGroup and so also all the following Slots having the same SlotGroup.

Comment: @Simone Why doesn't your cursor code take those factors into account?

Comment: I think I made some confusion: the cursor works correctly, unfortunately the alternative code I tried had issues on these cases ... I'm trying to write a piece of code that could work as the cursor also on this data sets

Comment: @Simone Your explanation for test set 6, slotgroup 46, does not match cursor results, as slot 49 remains the same by cursor code, and slot 50 becomes the start of a new slotgroup.

http://rextester.com/ENKG93481

Comment: I fear that is happening because there are duplicated slots, when you run all of them together